# Connect Visual Studio to custom Pages

Tags: visual-studio, publishing-page, development-enviroment

I would like to connect my Visual Studio to our Sharepoint Sites and edit them. I can see connections in the server explorer, but that is all. Can not open them.

I really do want to move away from: make change on .aspx file, find it in my folder, copy it to sharepoint designer, refresh the page.

This is really annoying to develop Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a SharePoint site as a drive in windows by using the site URL as the remote path for the mapping. After that you can use whatever editor you want to make changes.

This article covers the mounting process and has a link to a OS specific step by step:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj733519(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yes, this is definitely one way that is helping me a lot. Is this also best practice to do web development in Sharepoint? because i am searching for days now to find the correct way.

Comment: It is one of MS's advertised forms of editing SharePoint content. If you go to the Design Manager it'll actually tell you to do this to edit your Master pages and Page Layouts.